# Auto-rotation stopped working on iOS 7 XCode 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, rotation, xcode5

In interface builder, I selected, copied, and pasted a textField, switch, button, and label from my iPhone Storyboard's Flipside view controller into the iPad Storyboard's popup view controller.

After that I started getting weird errors on those exact items, about frames that "will be different at runtime" that would not go away, and they did not have disclosure triangles to tell me what to do to fix it. I tried removing all my constraints to fix it, and that didn't fix it. Later I imply deleted those items which had been pasted into the iPad Storyboard and the errors went away.

But now auto-rotation does not work in my app. The status bar (time & battery indicator) rotates but nothing else does. Except sometimes it does, but when it does, it gets stuck in the landscape orientation and won't rotate back properly.

At one point also I did set the main view controller from "Intrinsic" to "Landscape" just to see how it would look in Landscape mode, but later I changed it back.

I feel like my XIB files must have gotten corrupted somehow... how can I fix this? I've tried deleting all my constraints and re-adding them, both manually and by the recommended method. Setting the thing back to Portrait and then Intrinsic and cleaning my build folder. Updating to the latest Xcode Beta (which claims to have enhancements for auto-layout and constraints, which has always seemed buggy to me, with the constraints menu somtimes refusing to pop up, etc.). But still rotation just doesn't work.

What do I do? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that one. In my case, the app was never made for iOS 6. It does not crash. And everything in my case was done in Interface Builder.

Comment: Retracted, sorry. Are you returning NO from shouldAutorotate somewhere?

Comment: See my answer below. It was weird.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the fact that I was loading a UIAlert when the app launched. You could dismiss the alert but then the auto-rotation was broken. Once I got rid of the UIAlert everything was fine.

Weird.